# Trying to iterate through an obj-c object properties and copy them to another object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom object saved to NSUserDefaults. I don't use Core Data as it is way to much for my one object. I am trying to create a method that takes a new object of this type and combine it with the data in a saved object of this type.

Here is what I have so far, but it is erroring out because some objects are of different types (BOOL, NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, etc..).

```
if (request) {
    unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
    objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList(
        [AmbulanceRequest class], &numberOfProperties);

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
        NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        NSString *attributesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
            property_getAttributes(property)];

        if( nil == [request valueForKey:name]) { <--- error here BOOL cannot be nil
            [request setValue:[savedRequest valueForKey:name] forKey:name];
        }
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is:   `[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL`

UDPATE:

I am just using decoder and encoder. When encoding and decoding in general I never have issues. Just in the code above. For example, here is one property that is throwing the error.

Of course these are in the appropriate encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods.

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL * trip;
 self.roundTrip = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"trip"];
 [encoder encodeBool:self.roundTrip forKey:@"trip"];
```

//// UPDATE 2: //////

Here is the full code of my method. As you can see the object is pulled back and decoded way before any of this iterating through the properties happens. I have two BooRequests the old one and a new one. I am trying to take the properties of the old one and save them to the new one if the new one doesn't have those same properties.

```
+(void) saveRequest:(BooRequest*)request {

    // If current request then we need to save off the unSetPings
    BooRequest *savedRequest = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                                                                             objectForKey:kCurrentActiveRequest]];
    if(request){

        unsigned int numberOfProperties = 0;
        objc_property_t *propertyArray = class_copyPropertyList([BooRequest class], &numberOfProperties);

        #warning YO!!! this FOR LOOP is *NOT* done and probably doesn't even work!!!
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfProperties; i++)
        {
            objc_property_t property = propertyArray[i];
            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
            NSString *attributesString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:property_getAttributes(property)];

            if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation].allKeys containsObject:@"keyForNonMandatoryObject"]) {
                id thing = [request valueForKey:name];

                if(NULL == [request valueForKey:name] || nil == thing){
                    [request setValue:[savedRequest valueForKey:name] forKey:name];
                }
            }

            if(savedRequest) {
                request.unSentPings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:savedRequest.unSentPings];
            }

            request.nextButtonToShowIndex = savedRequest.nextButtonToShowIndex;
        } // end for loop

    } else {

        STPingSender *sender = [[STPingSender alloc] init];
        BooRequest *req = [BooRequest currentRequest];
        if(req && req.unSentPings && [req.unSentPings count] > 0){
            [sender sendToServer:((BooRequest*)[BooRequest currentRequest]).unSentPings];
        }
    }


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:request]
                                                          forKey:kCurrentActiveRequest];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Here is my ultimate goal I have a BooRequest that is saved locally from the server. I make changes to it locally. 90% of the time their are not updates from the server which I need to update locally. But when there are I need the new local data merged with the new server data. But the local data I add is only used locally, the server never uses this additional data. It only needs to be merged locally. The reason I am iterating is that I don't want to have to update this method everytime this Objective-c class gets a new property added to it. I want some dynamic code that just says iterate through the properties and when you find the properties that match on the old object and new object, copy the old object properties into the new ones.

Comment: Post the code in which you archive the object as well.

Comment: Its just simple decoder and encoder.  See update above.

Comment: I don't get anything here - show us the code that triggers decoding -- i mean... something must do this, since you claim a crash in the above code --if you don't know yet, set breakpoints to figure out when the decoding is attempted

Comment: oh and... where/how is your BOOL* trip used?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you really intend to have `BOOL*` as your property, instead of a standard primitive `BOOL`?

Comment: Using the runtime to enumerate properties is a bad idea to collect elements of a class to serialize: 1. computed properties should not be serialized but can't be detected, 2. non-property ivars are left out, 3. properties can be added by categories (for example on NSObject by some 3rd party library you are using). There are other reasons why this is a bad approach.

Comment: I have updated the question. @NikolaiRuhe I am not sure what you are talking about. See the last paragraph on what my ultimate goal is.

Comment: from your last pararapg I'd say u'd should do it the other way around: iterate over the server data's keys and map that to the local object properties. no weird runtime stuff needed.

Comment: What's the question, now?

Comment: Still the same question. Worrying about how the object is archived or unarchived has nothing to do with this question. The item is completely unarchived and in good working state before I try iterating through and merging the data in the properties. Please stop focusing on the archiving and unarchiving of the object. Its a rather simple question. How can I iterate through and objects properties and copy the data from object1 to object2 moving over the data, which might be an NSString, BOOL, NSNumber, etc...

Comment: If you don't care about archiving you should remove that from your question. Right now it's not clear what you want to do and where's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id dataObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCurrentActiveRequest];
BooRequest *savedRequest = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataObject];
```

when dataObject is nil, which means there is no such key in user defaults, the second line will emit the `[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL` error, in this case, you should not unarchive it, if the new BooRequest object is not nil, you can save the new object to user default directly.

```
id thing = [request valueForKey:name];
```

For properties that are of primitive type such as BOOL or NSInteger, the `thing` is `NO` and `0` respectively when you don't set the value of the properties, which means the `if(NULL == [request valueForKey:name] || nil == thing)` check is always false and the new request object is not updated from the old one. I suggest you to change those properties to NSObject type, so the check will pass.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* boolProperty;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *integerProperty;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to store a custom object in `NSUserDefaults` in the first place... that is usually more pain than it is worth.

Why not just create an `NSDictionary` and save that to `NSUserDefaults`?  Then your `BooRequest` class can init from dictionary as well as merge from dictionary.  You can also create a method `-saveToUserDefaults` method in `BooRequest` that saves it back when completed.  And depending on what `BooRequest` actually does you may not need a custom subclass if all you are doing is storing some key-value pairs.

It would be helpful to see what your local data looks like, and what your remote data looks like, and then the desired outcome.

Comment: BooRequest is my custom object. So are you saying scrap my custom object and use an NSDictionary instead? If so that would be way to much work as I then have to manually iterate through the server results to find the BooRequest when RestKit maps to my custom BooRequest automatically.

Answer (score -1):

- You shouldn't blindly iterate through all the object properties but choose those worth being saved.
- As said in another answer, don't use `NSUserDefaults` for this. If you don't want to use Core Data I recommend [serializing Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html). As a bonus you'll be able to inspect/manually edit your object values.